# How to update a datasource dynamically C#?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, datasource

I have calender that displays inforamtion based on the date selected. 
It is something like this:

```
string queryString = "SELECT * from events";
SqlCommand thisCommand = thisConnection.CreateCommand();
thisCommand.CommandText = queryString;
SqlDataReader reader = thisCommand.ExecuteReader();
if(true)
    queryString = "SELECT Text from events where repeat = 1";
else 
    queryString = "SELECT Text from events where repeat = 0";

GridView1.DataSource = reader ;
GridView1.Bind();
```

The error I am getting is  "The data source does not support server-side data paging"

Comment: that code cannot compile... `queryString` is not correctly declared in this sample

Comment: I fixed it, i forgot to paste the initial declaration.

Comment: Do you requiring `paging` behavior in your UI?

Comment: Yes, But that is not a huge requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You should use SqlDataAdapter instead to fill DataTable and then use the datatable as datasource for your gridview. SqlReader is class for fast access to sql data and it isn't suitable as datasource.

```
var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(thisCommand);
var table = new DataTable();
adapter.Fill(table);

GridView1.DataSource = table;
GridView1.Bind();
```

You'll be doing all sorting/paging on web server though - this operations are best handled directly on SQL server. So I suggest using ObjectDataSource or LinqDataSource and adjusting the queries appropriately to handle SQL-server-level paging/sorting.

Comment: When I change the selectedDates of the calendar I get this exeception: "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first"